# CakePHP v3.2.12 Debug Kit http://test/debug_kit/js/toolbar.js 404 (Not Found)

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-debug-kit

in CakePHP v3.2.12

I get GET http://test/debug_kit/js/toolbar.js 404 (Not Found)

When I try this:
cd webroot
ln -s ../vendor/cakephp/debug_kit/webroot debug_kit

I get this:

toolbar.js:53 GET http://test/debug_kit/toolbar/b977c7b2-a414-4970-8ac3-ef48e3e8982e 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Do you have install sqllite?

Comment: I use the MySQL database connection. The debug kit works when I do bin/cake server but not a normal website.

Comment: I had this issue and after spending hours tweaking various settings  I cleared all the files in `tmp` folder (leaving the folder structure in place) and suddenly DebugKit worked again.

Answer (score 1):

I found out I was missing AllowOverride All from my .conf file stated in the CakePHP documentation